# How prettify (newlines and indentation) an optimized HTML/JS file?

Tags: indentation, formatting, html, javascript

For example, I have the following bunch of characters (HTML): http://pastebin.com/pwTPp8wd

I thought everyone stumbled it upon a processed file, especially when someone would speed up the processing of large HTML/Javascript/whatever file. Then there must be a way to automate the indentation, without applying manual. However, I couldn't find anything about force indentation on a optimized file.

Any thoughts?

Comment: You want the function equivalent of a _HTML beautifier_ in Emacs?

Comment: A quick googling gave me this: https://github.com/yasuyk/web-beautify Do you want to try it out? The solution is not completely in emacs though.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can use the built-in `sgml-mode` for this.

1. `M-x sgml-mode` - Enable the `sgml-mode` major mode so that `sgml-pretty-print` command auto-loads.
2. `C-x h` - Select the whole buffer.
3. `M-x sgml-pretty-print`

To save space, below is only a part of the formatted text that I get on doing the above on your sample text in the question:

```html
<table border="4px" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="c31 c42">
  <tbody>
    <tr class="c4">
      <td class="c33" colspan="1" rowspan="1">
        <p class="c6">
          <span class="c12 c11">Veld
          </span>
        </p>
      </td>
      <td class="c35" colspan="1" rowspan="1">
        <p class="c7">
          <span class="c12 c11">Waarde(n)
          </span>
        </p>
      </td>
      <td class="c26" colspan="1" rowspan="1">
        <p class="c19">
          <span class="c12 c11">Null
          </span>
        </p>
      </td>
      <td class="c18" colspan="1" rowspan="1">
        <p class="c6 c38">
          <span class="c12 c11">Validatie
          </span>
        </p>
      </td>;
```

[[**Source**]](https://stackoverflow.com/q/137043/1219634)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, nice that this is built-in in Emacs. However, I found some minor faulty indentation, but overall, the `M-x sgml-pretty-print` is good enough. Thanks for the help.

Comment: `sgml-pretty-print` worked directly in Html+ mode :)

Answer (score 2):

The default HTML mode also works.

1. `C-x h` - Select the whole buffer
2. `M-x indent-region` (aka <kbd>C-M-\</kbd>)

Comment: That doesn't work if the newlines have been removed.

Comment: Agreed, that is a problem. Another thing: HTML is lax, a page with errors can often still load in a browser. I removed a </p> and </td>, but indent-region still worked.